# Jquery Div height not working on page load

Tags: jquery, html, height

I'm new to posting on forums so please let me know if I've missed anything. I've used Jquery to apply height to certain Divs. The height is basically set to 100% - 350px using this code:

```
function setSizes() {
    var containerHeight = $("#wrapper").height();
    $(".fluid_height").height(containerHeight - 350);
}
$(window).resize(function() { setSizes(); });
```

It does not register on page load, but does register as soon as you change the browser's window size. I have not found any conflict in the CSS. The Div is part of a Jquery Div-swap, and I hope it's not down to a conflict in the js.

Link: www.rockomole.com/geebiz_test/index (Divs are under Challenge -> Guidance and Criteria.

Let me know if you want me to post the CSS. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this code you only call setSizes when the page is resized. This does not happen on page load. You can call it explicitly yourself

```
$(document).ready( function() { setSizes(); });
```